# ColdFusion 9's site-wide error handler not working

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling, coldfusion-9

I have an error page,`anyError.cfm`, that looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <p>An error has occurred.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the CF web admin under `Server Settings > Settings > Site-wide Error Handler` I enter `\anyError.cfm`. When I navigate to `http://localhost:8500/some-url-that-doesnt-exist` I still get the default error page. So my question, how do I get a custom site-wide error page using CF9? It doesn't necessarily have to be through the web admin.

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: Where are you putting theanyError.cfm page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the value "anyError.cfm" instead of "\anyError.cfm" in the site-wide error handler setting.

Update, after seeing your update to your question I see now that you are generating a 404. Which is not for the site-wide error handler, it is for the missing template handler setting right next to it.

Try using a variable that doesn't exist instead to generate an error that will cause the site-wide error handler to display.

Comment: The web admin won't let me update without the slash. The error I get is `The file specified as the site wide error handler does not exist. The default error handler will be used until a replacement is created.`.

Comment: try it with a frontslash then, backslashes are evil

Comment: No dice, I added a screen cap of the error I am seeing (where /s is a non existent directory).

Comment: ahhh yes I see now, thanks, I realize that my question was stated incorrectly. I thought the sitewide error handler would pick up on the 404's, so +1 & A. However if you don't mind answering how I can get anyError.cfm to catch the 404's I would be very grateful, I put the same information, `/anyError.cfm`, in the `Missing Template Handler` box and I still get the 404.

Comment: I believe the missing template handler needs an absolute path. Like c:\coldfusion9\wwwroot\anyError.cfm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14549/discussion-between-johnthexiii-and-jason-dean)